# How to call a function from another c file

Tags: c, function, file

I have 4 files,
two text files with data
one main file called main.c
and one file with all function prototypes called funcs.h

I am attempting to call the functions in the main.c file.

```
main.c
#include "funcs.h"

int main () {

//declare all variables here
```

```
funcs.h

int output(int input1, int input2);
```

In which file would I write the function definitions, the main or the same file with the prototypes?
The function must also use input from the text files.

Thanks.

I included "prototypes.h" at the top of both files but I cant figure out how the two files connect

Comment: function definitions can go in any C file which will be compiled and **linked** with your main.c file.

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what you wre using to develop with. If you're using a compiler like gcc, the answer will be different (a command line, or make file) than if you're using an IDE like Visual Studio (where you would make a project that handles it).

Answer (score 0):

The example could be clearer.  In main.c you have:

```
#include "funcs.h"

int main(void) {
  output(1, 2);
}
```

The declaration in funcs.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCS_H
#define FUNCS_H

int output(int input1, int input2);

#endif
```

and implementation in funcs.c:

```
#include "funcs.h"

int output(int input1, int input2) {
   // ...
   return 0;
}
```

You can either build the whole thing in one go:

```
$ gcc funcs.c main.c -o my_program
```

or build the object files separately and then link the object files into an executable:

```
$ gcc -c funcs.c
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gcc -o my_program funcs.o main.o
```

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.